# Como atualizar uma DIV com PHP

Tags: php, div, atualização

Olá, eu li alguns tutoriais de como atualizar a cada tantos segundos(usando javascript, Jquery,etc) e queria saber se existe uma maneira de **atualizar uma DIV com o próprio PHP**, quando apertar um botão por exemplo.

Por exemplo, quando fazer uma pesquisa atualizar uma DIV especifica dentro do site sem atualizar a pagina inteira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#botao').click(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
            type      : 'post', 
            url       : 'teste.php', 
            data      : 'nome='+ $('#campo1').val() +'&sobrenome='+ $('#campo2').val(), 
            dataType  : 'html', 
            success : function(resultado){
                    $('#tabela').html(resultado);
                }
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível, para isso você precisa obrigatoriamente de uma linguagem client-side como o javascript.
Se usar apenas o PHP você pode construir a página atualizada e enviar ela inteira ao cliente novamente.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX + jQuery

Função `load()`

Com PHP não tem como por se tratar de uma linguagem que se trabalha no servidor.